# Intellige Idea java spring application don't starting debug

Tags: java, spring, debugging, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I have Spring project on Gradle. When i choice run - project starting, no problem, but i choice debug - project frozen when starting. When i add breakpoint and I click F8 and go through the project code sequentially, then project in DEBUG mode successfull start.
I don't undestand why can this be so.

technology stack
Java 8
versions = [
apacheCsv           : '1.5',
apachePoi           : '3.10.1',
aspectj             : '1.8.10',
dynamicreports      : '4.0.2',
fileupload          : '1.3.3',
greenmail           : '1.5.3',
hikari              : '3.2.0',
httpclient          : '4.5.5',
jackson             : '2.8.5',
jasperReports       : '6.4.0',
jjwt                : '0.7.0',
junit               : '4.12',
liquibase           : '3.5.3',
lombok              : '1.16.16',
microMeterPrometheus: '1.1.2',
mockito             : '2.7.5',
mybatis             : '3.4.4',
mybatis_spring      : '1.3.1',
mybatis_typehandlers: '1.0.2',
opencsv             : '3.8',
postgresql          : '42.2.2',
restAssured         : '3.0.3',
spring_boot         : '2.0.1.RELEASE',
spring_security_ldap: '4.2.5.RELEASE',
streamEx            : '0.6.5',
typesafeConfig      : '1.3.1',
unboundid           : '3.2.0',
velocity            : '2.0',
zxing               : '3.2.1'

Debug mode frozen after HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
`2021-06-01 19:59:02.751  INFO   --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed. 01-Jun-2021 19:59:16.390 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@ef0e70, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2598395c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@71f74dbf, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@59503a1d, org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter@6bc5d8df, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@67acb80f, com.mts.bigdata.wfm.security.JwtAuthenticationProcessingFilter@2a6a70af, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5056c52c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@335240d2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@60b71482, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@596c9f9c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@25d06af7, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@796f5790]`

Server Tomcat8, lib = *.war file.

Comment: What do you call a "freeze"? How do you able to step through the code if you say that in debug mode it freezes? Do you have a sample project?

Comment: I fix this problem. Perhaps, VMProperty add -Ddebug fix this problem. "Freeze" i meant what project startnig, but log  is not filled in after row "HikariPool-1 - Start completed. "    . And web controller response 404 error.